# In Tkinter how do def work?

Tags: button, tkinter, photo, function

I made a Tkinter book on a grid, the navergation buttons scroll down the left row and the photos are displayed on the right column spaning many rows so buttons display as they should. When making this Tkinter book.
I made a button on a grid

```
left1 = Button(win, text=" Captian Scarlet ")# win, is root master
left1.configure(command=but1)# but1 is my first def
left1.grid(row=1, column=0)# all the buttons are on the left list
```

This displays and works like a button without a def

Then I made a def

```
def but1():
    img = Image.open("captain_scarlett.gif")# loads the gif file
    intro = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)# loads image drivers I belevie
    right1 = Label(win, image=intro)# I think Lable is used the same as html <span>
    right1.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=13)# image formatting to display correctly with buttons
```

Because I had a lack of education at the time, I could only get the image to displaplay outside a def. So in frustration I posted
"this code works purfect when not put into a def".
When I settled down I needed knowledge that I couldn't find online so I asked the question:
So How do I get this code to work inside a def ?

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think it doesn't work? There's nothing special about Tkinter in this regard; anything that works outside a def definitely works inside a def. The only caveats are the same for all python code. For example, any variables you create inside the def are local unless declared otherwise, and objects (but not widgets) may get garbage collected after the def executes.

Probably what is happening is that you're creating the image and storing a reference to it in a local variable. When the def stops executing the image object is garbage collected. You'll need to keep a reference to the image that can persist. One simple solution might be to do `right1.image=intro`.

Comment: that right1.image=intro saved my whole software I conldn't of produced any Tkinter book with out that one line of code right1.image=intro

Answer (score 0):

**This code works purfecty. Now my production can go full steam ahead**

Here is the finished code

```
def but1():
    img = Image.open("captain_scarlett.gif")
    intro = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    right = Label(win, image=intro)
    right.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=14)
    right.image=intro
```